# MySQL: Writing data to a table and columns

Tags: mysql, database, insert-into

Doing a university course in web development and I've been sick all the time we went thru databases. I've read up on most stuff, like connect to mysql, select DB and that. But something I can't figure out is how to add data in the columns of a table.

I've tried what i could find online but I haven't found anything useful really... So I was wondering if anyone here could be so kind to show me how write stuff to a table with these columns: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/851/sqla.png/

I don't need help to select DB etc, just how to write those data into the db. Or a link to a guide for dummies like myself... I've tried a lot of different ways with

`mysql_query(INSERT INTO *** VALUES ****)`

But I cannot get it to work..

Any help would be really appreciated, feeling totally lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more precise?What means "I cannot get it to work.. ", please post exact SQL and exact error, then maybe someone help you.

Comment: Can you show your latest attempt and we can guide you in the right direction? I'd prefer not to just give you the answer if it is your homework assignment.

Comment: @rkosegi get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' (text, songid, insertdate) VALUES ('test', '1', now())' at line 1

code: mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `tblcomment` VALUES(NULL,'test',1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);")

Comment: @JohnFx My last "good" attempt has been overwritten.. in my frustration to fix it. The teacher said "use books and internet to figure this out"... trying to but its kinda hard.

Comment: looking thru w3schools insert tutorial,

Comment: @Mr.Havoc please post also SQL INSERT query and output of SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable. Thanks.Maybe songid is number and you are inserting varchar

Comment: @rkosegi

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblcomment` VALUES(NULL,'$fnamn',$enamn,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);")

Gives: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`tblcomment`, CONSTRAINT `comment_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`songid`) REFERENCES `tblsong` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

It seems that it needs something from the table tblsong... maybe a bad idea to try to figure it out with tblcomment when tblsong is empty..

What if we try with this table: http://imageshack.us/f/820/sll.png/ now we definatly shouldnt need another tbl to get it to work..

Why did i have to become ill..

Comment: This is the current php file to handle db: http://pastebin.com/4UzCgist

get errors like:
 Notice: Use of undefined constant kundnr - assumed 'kundnr' in C:\wamp\www\test\insert_kunder.php on line 20

 it writes to DB now... think i might starting to understand how it works...

Comment: sql error you posted means that you are inserting new row which refers to foreign key which value does not exist yet.Can you post SHOW CREATE TABLE output to check structure of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `song_id` is related to some other table so you would need to have a valid `song_id` in your insert request, but something like this should work:

```
 INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES(NULL,'Your Text',song_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Notice that the `song_id` should be replaced with a valid id if it's related to another table:

```
 $song_id = 1;
 $text = "Sample text";
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES(NULL,'$text',$song_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
```

You should also try checking the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should do the trick.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (text, songid, insertdate) VALUES ('TEXT VALUE', 'SONG ID', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

There's a fairly easy to understand reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: last column can be ignored, since has it's default value when a new row inserted.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you be more specific.

Comment: On the image of the structure insertdate had no under the null field which would imply it needs a value to be inserted. Just curious how that works with the default value...

Comment: If I understand your question, when a column set with `default value` option, if a new row inserted, and that doesn't contain a value to that column, the database engine will handle it and insert a value you already chose it before. If you want to try it, click on `change` for the column `text`, fill the field `default value` with a word by your chose, insert a new data to database with out specifying value for column `text`, and see what happen. **Ex:** `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (songid) VALUES ('SONG ID')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (text, songid, insertdate) VALUES ('your_text_here', 'your_song_id_here', now());
```

A useful guide if you want stuff like this is [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)